# What controls the port Silverlight will use for requesting clientaccesspolicy.xml?

Tags: silverlight, port, clientaccesspolicy.xml

My silverlight app calls our webservice, located at a different domain, using an address of the format

```
<host>:<port>/<servicename>/<call>
```

for example posting to

```
server:5678/ourservice/comment
```

Using fiddler, I saw that silverlight requests **clientaccesspolicy.xml** at the root

```
server/clientaccesspolicy.xml
```

So we add a listening to port 80, that successfully serves the policy file, which lets the app continue with its calls. My app works, and the suits are happy.

### The Problem

Coming to work today, the morning after, Silverlight suddenly tries to access the policy from the port the service uses, instead of root:

```
server:5678/clientaccesspolicy.xml
```

I cannot remember doing any changes that could have affected this. I even reverted everything I think could have caused this, without results.

### The Question

What controls the port Silverlight will use for requesting clientaccesspolicy.xml?

Is there anything I could read up on, to understand this apparently ambiguous behavior?